# How to initialize DropDownList with ListItems

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I  am trying to initialize a DropDownList and this is my select method:

```
public List<ListItem> metodShownAbove()
{
    List<ListItem> initlist = new List<ListItem>();
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        initlist.Add(new ListItem("--- all---", "-1"));
        initlist.Add(new ListItem("text1", "Value1"));
        initlist.Add(new ListItem("text2", "Value2"));
        initlist.Add(new ListItem("text3", "Value3"));
    }
    return initlist;
}
```

And this is on my aspx page:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDL" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    SelectMethod="metodShownAbove"/>
```

The initlist is returning what I want to return, text and value as shown above. But when I try to get the selected value or text, `DDL.SelectedItem.Value` and `DDL.SelectedItem.Text`, it is the same value, the first one in ListItem initlist. There is no property in DDL wich contains 'Value1'. What am I doing wrong, how to correctly insert values, so that I can read both, value and text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must set the `DataValueField` of the DropDownList to the `Value` property of the ListItems:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDL" runat="server" DataTextField="Text" DataValueField="Value" ... />
```

Here I also set the `DataTextField` to the `Text`property of the items.